# Generate a dictionary with keys and incrementing list values

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I need to generate a dictionary as a pattern in the following way as an example:

```
x = 3 #number of keys
y = 4 #the number of values in first key, incremented in each following key
```

The desired output is:

```
{1:[0,1,2,3],2:[0,1,2,3,4],3:[0,1,2,3,4,5]}
```

How can I generate this output?

Answer (score 4):

Is this ok to you?

```py
x = 3
y = 4
my_list = {}
for i in range(1, x + 1):
    my_list[i] = list(range(y))
    y += 1
```

Or one line python using dict comprehension(maybe harder to understand):

```
x = 3
y = 4
my_list = {i + 1: list(range(y + i)) for i in range(x)}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use a dictionary comprehension:

```py
{i: list(range(j)) for i, j in zip(range(1, x + 1), range(y, y + x))}
```

This outputs:

```py
{1: [0, 1, 2, 3], 2: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4], 3: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]}
```